# Using a 3rd monitor on a hardware switch with dual display Graphics card

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, multiple-monitors

Is there a way to fool Kubuntu into thinking that a 3rd monitor on a hardware switch is the same monitor - same screen resolution etc? And therefore be able to switch between a second and third monitor? I know there must be to be honest as I've had it working for a while but since my move from Unity to KDE after a week ago it has stopped working.

Nvidia GT 705 Graphics card - supports two monitors at any one time.

Tried the 3rd monitor and it does show a display but not when switching. Only when a dual monitor set is in place.

The 3rd monitor can support 16:9 as it is a TV with VGA connection. I have however got it set to 1024*768 to use for both - this previously worked.

I can get it to work up until the point I actually login. I can do this by deleting `.config/monitors.xml` and setting resolution to 1024*768 instead of auto and refresh to 60Hz instead of auto. And then saving the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file without merging the file. Then reboot and dual screen on third monitor appears - I login: then blank screen again. Input can't be handled. Clearly seems to be down to resolution and refresh rate being reset on login . Any suggestions?

It works in Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it a bit by trial and error. I just went into display configuration under system settings and picked the correct screen resolution and refresh rate for the third monitor and this time it worked.

I had deleted `monitors.xml` from `/home/user/.config/monitors.xml`

This was a very obvious solution and one I'm sure I tried before so I'd be  interested if someone could offer a more suitable explanation or solution.